# Как уменьшить серверное время на час?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть серверное время, обновляющееся в реальном времени.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="timer"></div>

<button id="plus">+</button>
<button id="minus">-</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function update() {
          $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'datetime.php',
           timeout: 1000,
           success: function(data) {
              $("#timer").html(data); 
              window.setTimeout(update, 1000);
           }
          });
        }
        update();

        $('#plus').click(function(){ 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: 'datetime.php',
                //...
            })
        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

datetime.php

```
<?php 
    $msg     = date('d/m/Y h:i:s');
    $msgPlus  = date('d/m/Y h:i:s', strtotime("+1 hour"));
    $msgMinus = date('d/m/Y h:i:s', strtotime("-1 hour"));
    echo $msg;
?>
```

При клике на + серверное время должно увеличиваться на час. Как реализовать такое? Как ajax'ом вытащить переменную msgPlus из php и вставить в `<div id="timer"></div>`?

Comment: К примеру: по-умолчанию разница=0, при клике на "+" разница=+3600сек, вывод в браузер = время+разница.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/timezones.php

Comment: Не понятна задача. Зачем эта муть? Зачем менять серверное время?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как вариант на клиенте создать переменную-счетчик, если пользователь нажмет плюс, то она увеличится на один, если минус, то уменьшится на один.

Клиент:
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

```
    var counter = 0;

    $('#plus').on('click', function (event) {
        counter++;
        update();
    });

    $('#minus').on('click', function (event) {
        counter--;
        update();
    });

    function update() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'datetime.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'counter=' + counter,
            success: function (response) {
                 $("#timer").html(response); 
            }
        });

    }        

});
```

А на сервере делать примерно такое:

```
$counter = $_POST['counter'] ?? 0;
echo date('d/m/Y h:i:s', time() + (int)$counter * 3600);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Не могли бы вы подробнее показать связку js + php?

Comment: Посмотрите, добавил еще клиента

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно!